# Sending Emails in Nestjs

Tags: email, nestjs, nodemailer

I am trying to send email in NestJs but seems to stuck at a weird error.

```js
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'templateName' of 'precompile(...)' as it is undefined.  
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:363:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:573:11)
```

I am not sure what's going on the only solution I was able to find was to put ''./'' in front of the template names but I am not sure why would that work also it isn't even working in my case.

This is how i am trying to send it

```js
this.mailService.sendEmail(
            emailAddress,
            [], // cc
            [], // bcc
            "Pretty Subject Line", // subject
            "./verify-email", // template
            { // context
                name: "tetsName",
                verifyLink
            }
        );
```

templates folder is in root directory

Comment: Can you send your module file with template dir settings, please?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot set header error mostly occurs when you are sending a response after once you have sent a response. Take a look at the following code

```
//This does not work
res.send("This is a Response");
res.send("This is a second response");
```

If you are doing something like this, then it won't work. Try a logic that does all the tasks you want in one go or use may

```
res.write("This is a response"):
res.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me,this is a template file path issue. Review your template.dir in your MailerModule config, and compare it to your project "dist" directory. if your template file path is "dist/templates/template.hbs" then your template.dir should be ${process.cwd()}/templates else if your dist directory is "dist/src/templates/template.hbs" ,which is depend on your compile configs. then your template.dir config should be join(__dirname, 'templates')